# Retrofit query parameter is not taking values greater than 2^32

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to fetch some data from twitter APIs by using user_id. But retrofit fails to connect for **userId** > Integer upper limit (of int type variables) even though **id** variable is set to be a **long** and I keep on getting ERROR.

I have a way to fetch this information via other means, but I wanted to know if retrofit doesn't support long type variables?

Here is the error message -

```
01-26 11:50:17.600    4505-4505/com.kshitij.twitter E/CONNECTION ERROR﹕ com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 2843025282 at line 1 column 17 path $.id
```

Function making the call.

```
    cs.getUser(userId, new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void success(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result<User> userResult) {
            AddUserObject userObject = createAddUserObject(userResult.data);
            addUserToDB(userObject);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Log.e("CONNECTION ERROR", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
```

Following is the interface for the same.

```
public static interface CustomService {

    @GET("/1.1/users/show.json")
    void getUser(@Query("user_id") long id, Callback<User> cb);

    @GET("/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json")
    void getTweets(@Query("user_id") long id, @Query("count") long count, Callback<List<Description>> cb);
}
```

Comment: Show the actual exception or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` Java object is declaring an `int id;` when it should be a `long`.

Since an ID has no numerical significance, you're actually better off always using it as a `String`.

Comment: Yeah, how could I miss this. I must have messed it up while making json to pojo. Thanks :)